# Guava cache allow stale reads?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am using a Guava cache hold and periodically refresh some stats that we collect from a long running database query. The problem I am seeing at the moment is that all threads have to wait for the refresh, rather than allowing the callers to get the expired cached value. Is there a way in Guava cache to allow the stale reads?

The cache is built as such

```
 cache = CacheBuilder.<DateType, List<DataValueEventQuality>> newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(cacheExpirySeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

And I retrieve from the cache using `cache.get(key, Callable)`

Comment: How are you refreshing the data? From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) _The old value (if any) is still returned while the key is being refreshed_.

Comment: See my edit with more information.

Comment: And there is no way you can make it into a `LoadingCache`?

Answer (score 2):

yes i know this is old, but i figured this out today so heres the answer: taken from the google docs:  https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#refresh

key part is that you want to refreshAfterWrite instead of expireAfterWrite

```
// Some keys don't need refreshing, and we want refreshes to be done      asynchronously.
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .refreshAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph load(Key key) { // no checked exception
           return getGraphFromDatabase(key);
         }

         public ListenableFuture<Graph> reload(final Key key, Graph prevGraph) {
           if (neverNeedsRefresh(key)) {
             return Futures.immediateFuture(prevGraph);
           } else {
             // asynchronous!
             ListenableFutureTask<Graph> task = ListenableFutureTask.create(new Callable<Graph>() {
               public Graph call() {
                 return getGraphFromDatabase(key);
               }
             });
             executor.execute(task);
             return task;
           }
         }
       });
```

Comment: in my case I found follow issue, this approach caused double loading for caches. Did you find a way to solve this issue?

Comment: In case the `reload` and `load` methods are the same, instead of implementing the `reload` with asynchronous task you can use [CacheLoader.asyncReloading](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#asyncReloading-com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) like this: `CacheLoader.asyncReloading(new CacheLoader(...), executor)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the wrong method for this. From the [documentation for `LoadingCache`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) there are two methods:

```
void put(K key, V value)
```

> Associates value with key in this cache. If the cache previously
>   contained a value associated with key, the old value is replaced by
>   value.

This is atomic, the cache has to wait.

```
void refresh(K key)
```

> Loads a new value for key key, possibly asynchronously. While the new
>   value is loading the previous value (if any) will continue to be
>   returned by get(key) unless it is evicted

You don't say what sort of cache you are using or show any code so I don't know whether you are using a `LoadingCache`. But you need to use `refresh` for the cache to reload the value which still allowing the old value to be read.

Comment: If the new value gets loaded and the old value is there in the memory then the total memory consumed will be = new value memory + old value memory. If that is the case then wont this cause the program to run out of heap memory? If not then can you please tell me how is this avoided ?

Comment: Can you please explain why ??

Comment: Since guava cache is not using any persistent storage, the stale value is getting stored in memory only. If not then how is this being handled ??

Comment: Why would you think both values are stored at any point @prashant?

Comment: The requirement is that while refreshing the cache, if the refresh fails then the stale value should be displayed, if not then the stale value should be discarded and the refresh value should be returned. Thus till the entire refresh is done the stale value is in memory and once the refresh completes, till the stale value is discarded both are in memory.

Comment: What does "_till the stale value is discarded_" mean, @prashant? Java is a garbage collected language; therefore in the most basic sense, this statement is true of any declared variable. Once it is no longer referenced, it is eligible for GC - it is not discarded from memory until the GC runs (and even then possibly not). I'm not sure what the point you are trying to make is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122686/discussion-between-prashant-and-boris-the-spider).

Comment: hey guys I have a question
related to cache refreshing.
Lets say I have an in memory cache which is 20 GB and which is also the size of my heap...now when I refresh the cache if the store the stale cache and then refresh the cache at one point I would have 40 GB since I have loaded a new cache object, and hence would go out of memory
how should I handle this can you please tell me